# Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7

I know there are plenty of questions related to this, and they all seem to point to the fact that the compiled version and the .net version on the server is different, mainly that the compiled version is 4.5 while the server only has 4.5. I can guarantee that the code has been compiled for 4.0.

The odd part is that we get the error only happens after a deploy, which is being done via an automated process. And after that, if I reset IIS, or stop-start the apppool (recycling doesn't work), the application starts working again. If the application compilation was not correct, I am assuming I would get this error always, right? Why does reseting the apppool fix this? I'm really out of ideas at this point...

Comment: Something loads 4.5 runtime first and than your app starts - check list of DLLs loaded when you see the error (you don't need VS if you can't get it on server, WinDbg would be enough or even just dump).

Comment: something in my app? or on the server?

Comment: Server. Something that happens before your app loaded by w3wp process. Maybe another site built for the other of 4.0/4.5 but sitting in the same appPool?

Comment: installed windbg - attached to w3wp.exe - none of the DLLs in there seem to be from 4.5... not very familiar witn windbg - is that what I'm supposed to be doing?

Comment: WinDbg should show list of DLL on load. Make sure there is no mscrolib that you don't expect (attach when it works and attach when it does not to see if there is rogue mscorlib). Command to list all modules is [lm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552026%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - I think `lmf` is one that also includes full path.

Comment: Hmm - I opened up the gui interface, which isn't showing anything - attach to which process?

Comment: w3wp.exe (the one IIS uses to hos AppPools, I think it is the same for all versions of IIS, but I could be wrong).

Comment: I was able to get the list of DLLs, and the only mscorlib was this one: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\bc19222db4406c472d9aa1f8b6e0f470\mscorlib.ni.dll

... and there are tons of DLLs in w3wp.exe - how do I find which one could be 4.5?

Comment: I was hoping you'll get one from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib (not NGen'ed) so it is easier to check version... Can you check what version you have in that folder (check properties of the file->details, should be 17929+ for 4.5). NGen'ed image should match... Any chance that your setup script installs 4.0 starts IIS and than installs 4.5? (I doubt it is possible but)... Did you manage to get dll location for both cases (works/fails) as it may give you reason... Since 4.0->4.5 is in-place upgrade something strange should happen to allow 4.0 version of DLL be loaded...